# how we need to export the pdf content numeric data align to right

Tags: datatables, numeric, text-alignment, export-to-pdf

how to align the numeric data to right in exportpdf jquery datatable

i have tried this below code but it getting for all columns i need only for numeric data columns

doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'right';

doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'right';

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
// Change 5th column to right align
 var rowCount = doc.content[1].table.body.length;
 for (i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {
    doc.content[1].table.body[i][5].alignment = 'right';
 };
```

Refer this for [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894339/align-one-column-with-pdfmake-and-datatables)

Comment: i need full numeric columns not single column

Comment: just add all columns index in loop like this doc.content[1].table.body[i][4].alignment = 'right';

Comment: Yes if you do changes in UI it will take time,  Better get PDF generated from Backend ...  for Time issue

Comment: no when i taking loop it showing error table undefined

Comment: var rowCount = document.getElementById("example").rows.length;             
                for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                 for (var j = 0; j< a.length; j++) {
               debugger;
                         var a2=a[j];                       
               doc.content[1].table.body[i][a2].alignment = 'right'; 
               }         
            };  i have tried this getting error table undefined